# Shiny: use styleColorBar with data from two data frames

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to display a table in Shiny, where numbers will be displayed from one data.frame (or data.table), but the size of bars will be taken from another data.frame. For instance, absolute values will be displayed, but -log(p-values) from another table (identically arranged) will determine the width of color bars.

This is my mock code:

```
  output$pivot_table = DT::renderDataTable(
    dt <- datatable(

      {
        a <- data.frame(matrix(1, 20, 5))
        pval_data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n = 100), 20, byrow = T))
        print(pval_data)
        a
      }

    ) %>% formatStyle(names(a),
                      background = styleColorBar(range(pval_data), 'lightblue'),
                      backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                      backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                      backgroundPosition = 'center')
  )
```

printed `pval_data`:

```
            X1          X2          X3           X4          X5
1   0.968418606 -1.87152557  0.61937740 -0.143097511  0.65508855
2  -0.007557229  0.08118509  0.15390863  1.375011375  0.52879595
3  -0.310230367  0.24825819 -0.61521934  0.994227019  0.99756573
4  -0.347770895 -0.91282709  0.79575280  0.234287011 -1.24957553
5   1.699646126 -0.22895201  0.15979995  0.223626312 -1.61600316
6  -0.490930813  0.32298741 -0.81244643  0.474731264  0.09482891
7  -1.118480311  0.42816708 -1.60837688  0.923083220 -0.18504939
8  -0.613107600  0.85641186  0.50027453 -0.682282617  0.78146768
9  -1.191377934 -0.65435824  1.18932459 -0.698629523 -0.06541897
10 -1.149737780  2.47072440 -0.06468906 -0.150334405  1.23995530
11  0.877889198 -0.58012128  0.69443433  2.180587121 -1.32090173
12 -0.323477829 -1.46837648  1.38017226 -1.223060038  1.92034573
13 -1.016861096 -0.62798484  0.22159954 -1.601450990 -0.25184806
14  0.392432490 -0.42233004 -0.64490950 -1.491724171 -0.71931626
15 -1.270341425  0.79922671  0.82034852 -0.109127778 -0.73276775
16  0.713192323  1.01199542  1.08499699  0.328685928  0.98869534
17 -1.491903472 -0.40431848  0.47478220 -1.856996096  1.67946815
18 -0.089676087 -1.16068035 -0.69258182 -0.002303751 -1.39804362
19  0.504820216  0.88694633 -0.52855791  0.330452562 -1.57425961
20  0.899474044 -0.41477379 -0.34950206 -0.062604686  2.26622730
```

My table looks like this now:

[image: ones]

Instead, I want it the bars to be proportional to pval_data, like this (but with ones instead of the pval_data numbers in the table):

[image: rands]

Thanks!

P.S. The other question is: if I wanted the colors to be conditional, e.g., if I wanted the color to turn red if the corresponding pval is below N, how would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the `styleColorBar` function creates some Javascript code to make the background based on the `range(pval_data)`, but that code is applied to the values of the datatable that is drawn, in this case `a`.

One trick could be to `cbind` `a` and `pval_data`, and pass that to the output so that all the data necessary to do what you went is passed to the browser.

You could then color the background of the first five columns (`a` in this case) according to the values in the five last columns (`pval_data`) and hide the last 5 columns if you don't want them displayed.

Here's an example:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
    server <- function(input, output) {

  a<-reactive({
    data.frame(matrix(1, nrow=input$obs, ncol=5))
  })

  pval_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n = input$obs*5), ncol=5))
  })

  output$pivot_table = DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(cbind(a(),pval_data()), options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6:10, visible = FALSE)),rowCallback = JS(
  paste0("function(row, data) {

        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
           value = data[i+5]
           if (value < ",input$cutoff,") backgroundValue =",styleColorBar(range(pval_data()), 'lightblue')[1],"
           else backgroundValue =",styleColorBar(range(pval_data()), 'red')[1],"
           $('td', row).eq(i).css('background',backgroundValue);
           $('td', row).eq(i).css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
           $('td', row).eq(i).css('background-position','center');
           $('td', row).eq(i).css('background-size','98% 88%')
         }
         }"))
)))

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 5, max = 20, value = 10),
      sliderInput("cutoff", "Cutoff:", min = -5, max = 5, value = 0,step=0.5)
    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput('pivot_table')
  )
)))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the `options` part of the `datatable`, `columnDefs` is used to hide the last 5 columns, and `rowCallback` to color the background. With this code, the background will be lightblue if the values is less than 0 and red if it is above 0.

Comment: That looks perfect. Let me give it a try in the office, and if everything works, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, quick question. I am getting `Error in styleColorBar(range(pval_data), "lightblue") : 
  object 'pval_data' not found`. Does pval_data have to be global?

Comment: Also, if, instead of `value < 0`, I want the user to enter the cutoff value and pass to the JS, is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I posted a mock shiny example, and added all the other background options to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks, looks good! I accepted the answer and will award the bounty soon (it says I can do it in seven hours).

Comment: Glad it works, you can always leave it and award it in a few days to see if someone comes up with something smarter.

Comment: Hey, I have implemented your function, but for some reason the pivot table is ‘skipping’ some values (really large raw values with low p-values don’t get colored in). Here’s my code: http://git.io/vsvHH I’d appreciate any leads.

Comment: Actually, I got it! Increasing the range by a small increment (0.001) makes sure that the top values are included.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this could be simplified and it may not be necessary to write JavaScript: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html Not 100% sure, though.

Comment: @Yihui, I definitely tried tinkering with different options/approaches from the examples on that link before. One approach I had is to find the indices of the p-values < cutoff from the pval_data table, and then use `styleEqual` to assign color = red to whatever cells in pivot_table had values corresponding to those indices.

This is worse because a) it doesn’t use the bars, like @NicE’s approach does, b) two distributions might have the same mean but different variance and as a result different p-values, on the opposite sides of the cutoff (unlikely down to a decimal, but in theory possible).

Comment: But I would definitely appreciate any further suggestions. Also if `styleEqual` function could be changed so that assigning color values by an index rather than a value were possible, that’d be helpful.

Comment: Notice that here the closer the negative value is to 0 the longer the red bar! I am not sure if this is intended. Normally you would expect the red bar to grow when the values get more negative. 
My suggestion how to fix that problem is in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830382/shiny-dt-stylecolorbar-different-color-for-positive-and-negative-values/34238993#34238993 which relies heavily on the answer above.

Comment: If anyone wants bar to be just proportion/percentage, it is enough to use `styleColorBar(c(0,1), 'lightblue')[1]`