# styleColorBar Center and shift Left/Right dependent on Sign

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am looking to create bars that when using DT's `datatable` appear in the middle of the cells of a column and reach out left or right depending on whether the value in the cell is positive or negative.

I have tried using the function `styleColorBar` and changing the argument `backgroundPosition` to `'left'` or `'center'` however with each try the bars still appear to the right of the cell and always go to the left.

I can't find an example from R code, but have attached an example of what can be done on Excel; the colours aren't necessary but if included that would be a bonus.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question but it lacks the effort the way it is presented. Please add a a reproducible example. You could add a minimal example where you used `backgroundPosition = 'left'` so that people can use it and try to find a solution. It is very unlikely that someone (including myself) will take the time to write the code that produces the situation described here and then try to find a solution...

Comment: I understand what I wrote wasn't easily understandable; have rewritten it so reads a bit better. Probably still not great but hopefully makes more sense than before!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could make a custom `styleColorBar` function that uses the CSS gradients (same as the original `styleColorBar`) to make the kind of bars you want.

Here is an example (sorry for the long line, adding new lines breaks the CSS):

```
color_from_middle <- function (data, color1,color2) 
{
  max_val=max(abs(data))
  JS(sprintf("isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value < 0 ? 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent ' + (50 + value/%s * 50) + '%%, %s ' + (50 + value/%s * 50) + '%%,%s  50%%,transparent 50%%)': 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 50%%, %s 50%%, %s ' + (50 + value/%s * 50) + '%%, transparent ' + (50 + value/%s * 50) + '%%)'",
             max_val,color1,max_val,color1,color2,color2,max_val,max_val))
}
```

Using some test data:

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(rep("a",9)),value=c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4))

datatable(data) %>%
  formatStyle('value',
              background=color_from_middle(data$value,'red','blue'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly even for multiple columns!

Comment: Hi @NiceE, I was just wondering if you might know how to accomplish the very same thing in gt package. For more details, here my SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442840/r-gt-package-conditional-bars-as-part-of-a-html-table