# styleColorBar: have the size of the color bar be proportional to absolute values of a column

Tags: r, datatable, dt

With `styleColorBar`, how can I get size of the color bar to be proportional to the *absolute* value of a column? In contrast to this, in the example below, looking at the `cyl` column, the red bar is larger for greater values.

**Code:**

```
data <- head(mtcars[,1:4])
data[,2] <- -data[,2]
data
out <- datatable(data, rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle('mpg',
              background = styleColorBar(data$mpg, 'lightblue'),
              backgroundSize = '95% 50%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'right') %>%
  formatStyle('cyl',
              background = styleColorBar(data$cyl, 'red'),
              backgroundSize = '95% 50%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'right')
out
```

**Result:**
[image]
I am aware that very similar questions have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018521/shiny-use-stylecolorbar-with-data-from-two-data-frames) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521828/stylecolorbar-center-and-shift-left-right-dependent-on-sign).

But both examples seem more intricate than mine. The former deals with formatting a column based on another column. The latter has the direction of the color bar depend on the sign. I thought that perhaps a simpler trick exists for my case...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one hackish way: `styleColorBar` produces some JavaScript, where you can substitute `value` by `Math.abs(value)`. To get the limits right, I also took `abs(data$cyl)`:

```
library(DT)
data <- head(mtcars[,1:4])
data[,2] <- -data[,2]
data
out <- datatable(data, rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle('mpg',
              background = styleColorBar(data$mpg, 'lightblue'),
              backgroundSize = '95% 50%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'right') %>%
  formatStyle('cyl',
              background = gsub(
                "value", "Math.abs(value)", 
                styleColorBar(abs(data$cyl), 'red'),
                fixed=T),
              backgroundSize = '95% 50%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'right')
out
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

background = styleColorBar(c(0,data$mpg), 'lightblue'),

It works on my shiny app. It just creates a 0 limit to the data, which solves the problem.